# Destructuring a method from an object

Tags: javascript, html, methods, destructuring, template-literals

I was working with dates and such:

```
window.onload = () => {
  setInterval(
    () => {
      
      
      let currentTimeObj = new Date()
      
      let {currentSeconds: getSeconds()} = currentTimeObj ;
      
      currentTime.innerHTML = `${currentSeconds} `;
      
      
    }
   , 1000);
};
```

Problem is I want to assign the method from the date object called, `getSeconds()` to a variable and use it as a template literal. I'm trying to destructure `getDay()`, `getHours()` , etc. 'cause I want to do it on one line. If that isn't possible, or isn't reccomended, please tell me.

It outputs, `Invalid destructuring assignment target`, I've looked that up on google, I didn't get any clue what to do.

Got any tips? If not all I can think of doing is using the ol' fashioned
`"..." + variable + "..."` .

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `let getSeconds() = currentTimeObj.currentSeconds` and that is invalid. What are you trying to do? What does `getSeconds` look like?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was trying to do it on a single line; destructuring other methods and such, I edited the post, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was trying to do it on a single line; destructuring other methods and such, I edited the post, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three issues:

- You cannot *call* a function when that function variable needs to be assigned.
- The destructuring syntax `{ a: b } =`  will create a variable `b`, not `a`. So your attempt could have looked like `{ getSeconds(): currentSeconds } =`. But the first issue still applies.
- Even if you assigned the function without attempt to call it, it will not work. If you did: `{ getSeconds: currentSeconds } =`, you would assign the `getSeconds` function to `currentSeconds`. But for this particular function a correct `this` must be set for it to work. So you would then have to call it as `currentSeconds.call(currentTimeObj)`, which does not give you the code-saving you would have hoped for.

So compare some of the working alternatives:

```js
let currentTimeObj = new Date();
// Longer:
let {getSeconds: currentSeconds} = currentTimeObj;
console.log(currentSeconds.call(currentTimeObj));
// Alternative, still long:
currentSeconds = currentTimeObj.getSeconds.bind(currentTimeObj);
console.log(currentSeconds());
// Shorter:
console.log(currentTimeObj.getSeconds());
```